# Use hostname in Django Templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I am developing a django app and want to use relative `a href` url paths, as I develop on `localhost` and will be working on `www.example.com`. What is the best way to make a relative link like this in my template.html files?

Comment: If you are using relative urls, you don't need the host name.

Comment: Look into using the built-in template tag [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Answer (score 3):

That's ok. You can get **relative url** using the following in **Django** template(but for making REST API calls you should use **absolute url**).

```
{{ request.path }}
```

**eg.** In home page,

```
<a href="{{ request.path }}contact/">Contact</a>
```

Suppose my server is running on **localhost** and listening on port **8000** and I visit **home page**, then the above will be interpreted by django as follows,

```
<a href="/contact/">Contact</a>
```

In case of making REST API calls use the following in your template with **HOST**, **PORT** and **PATH**(**eg.** In home to get all posts),

```
<a href="{{request.scheme}}://{{request.get_host}}{{ request.path }}posts/">All posts</a>
```

And it will be rendered as follows,

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/">All posts</a>
```

I have one little example as [send_contact_data.js](https://gist.github.com/hygull/151ef218600afb4981dc991b494903bc). Visit and see line **8**.

Comment: Doing this gives me a URL like: http://%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: No, it should work, `%20` is showing some spaces are there before 127. Can you please check?